# Printing random number

Tags: c++, helper

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char gun;
    char att;

    cout << "Guns" << endl;

    cout << "[1]    AK" << endl;
    cout << "[2]    MP5" << endl;
    cout << "[3]    M2" << endl;
    cout << "[4]    SAR" << endl;
    cout << "[5]    Tommy" << endl;
    cout << "[6]    Custom" << endl;
    cin >> gun;

    cout << "[A]    Holosight" << endl;
    cout << "[B]    Simplesight" << endl;
    cout << "[C]    Silencer" << endl;
    cout << "[D]    Muzzel Boost" << endl;
    cout << "[E]    Muzzel Break" << endl;
    cout << "[F]    8x Zoom Scope" << endl;
    cout << "[G]    16x Zoom Scope" << endl;
    cout << "[H]    Lasersight" << endl;
    cin >> att;

    switch (gun) {

    case'1':
        if (gun = 1)
            cout << 'test' << endl;
        else
            cout << "Wrong Command" << endl;
        break;
    }

}
```

When I run this and select 1 (code is only half-built) it prints "1952805748". I have tried adding more cases and it still has this problem.

Can someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: In `if(gun = 1)` there are two errors. First of all, you are using the assignment operator. It should be `==` instead. Second, you are comparing a `char` with an `int`. You need to put single quotes around `1`.

Comment: ... third, think about each and every *keystroke* you tap when running this: Is there a key between the gnu selection and the model selection? Any key at all ?

Comment: Reminder:  one `=` for assignment, two for equality: `==`.

Comment: All those `endl`s; that stream is most definitely flushed. Seriously: `'\n'` ends a line. You don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues here:

```
if (gun = 1)
    cout << 'test' << endl;
```

that's not a comparison; gun is always assigned the value `1`, and the `if` condition is always true. The comparison operator is `==`.

Also, you are printing out `'test'`, which is why you are getting the weird number. You need to print `"test"`.

Also note that `gun` is a char, so you might want to compare against the char `'1'`.

Also, avoid `using namespace std;`